# Do new LCD TVs have TFT?

Tags: lcd, history

I am writing an essay about LCDs. None of the websites I've used mention anything about the dates and eras that newer technologies were used in LCDs, so wondering, does anyone know whether TFT is still being used in LCDs these days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of LCD displays made today use one or more TFTs per pixel. For displays over a certain resolution (probably > 640 by 480 pixels) like TVs or smartphones TFT driving is necessary. When displays were smaller than that so-called passive matrix addressing was possible. You might still see smaller displays that do not use TFT - say a monochrome display in a remote control.

Note that OLED technology (the main competitor) of LCD technology also use TFTs in the pixels.